# Vertical to horizontal scrolling and back

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I'm currently trying to learn something new regarding CSS / HTML and JS. However, I'm facing a JS issue that I am unable to fix.

The goal is simple: the user scrolls down until the `.h-scroll` div is visible. Once the `.h-scroll` div is visible, the user can no longer scroll down. From this point scrolling down scrolls will scroll the `.h-scroll` div sideways to the right. Scrolling up would mean scrolling the `.h-scroll` div to the left. Once the `.h-scroll` div is fully scrolled to the right the users can continue scrolling down on the webpage.

I have tried the CSS only approach where you rotate the contents of the div as seen here:

[Scroll left if user scroll down ( horizontal scrolling )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217143/scroll-left-if-user-scroll-down-horizontal-scrolling)

However, this has the issue that scrolling down to scroll right only works when the mouse is within the div.

The jQuery code below has also been tried however the issue here is that scrollLeft -= 100vw and scrollRight += 100vw do not simply scroll to the next div and stop working after moving only a tiny bit to the left or right. I have no idea how this bit of code is generally called so looking it up always brings me to `use overflow-x: scroll` while this is obviously not the answer

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var offsetTop = $('.h-scroll').offset().top;
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var scrollTrigger = offsetTop - windowHeight + 100;

    if (scrollTop >= scrollTrigger) {
      $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
      $('.h-scroll').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
      $('.h-scroll').animate({
        scrollLeft: '+=100vw'
      }, 1000);
      console.log("scroll down");
    } else {
      $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
      $('.h-scroll').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
      $('.h-scroll').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: '-=100vw'
      }, 500);
      console.log("scroll up")
    }
  });

  $('.h-scroll').on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollLeft() >= $('.h-scroll')[0].scrollWidth - $(this).outerWidth()) {
      $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
      $('.h-scroll').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.h-scroll {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.h-scroll div {
  color: black;
  width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100vw;
  color: white;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="h-scroll">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```